# Bundle savedIntanceStatem "error"

Tags: android, eclipse

My Code:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class KlassenActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_5aklassen);

            if(savedInstanceState == null) {

            } else {

            }

    }
```

I have tried a lot but I couldn't find what I have done wrong...

Help me!!!

the error comes up in the line

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

this is the error:

```
"savedInstanceState cannot be resolved to a variable"
```

The whole code (in progess :D):

```
package com.example.hvt;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class KlassenActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

PlaceholderFragment taskFragement;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_5aklassen);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            taskFragement=new PlaceholderFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager

        } else {

        }

    }

    public boolean onKeyDown (int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            startActivity(new Intent(KlassenActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstancesState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }
    }
    public static class TechCrunchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
            return null;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nowt wrong that I can see. Have you tried a Clean/Re-build?

Comment: i think so... but the error allways comes back :(

Comment: can you try to give a better example, thanks

Comment: I just edited the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function declaration, `savedInstanceState` is misspelled as `savedIntanceState`